# Extract previews in batch and name preview using inodes?

Tags: exiftool

Is is possible to extract previews in batch (from images in a folder) and name the preview using the image's inode?

Example output:

```
path/to/previews_folder/{image_parent_folder_inode}/{image_inode}.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but if you are asking if exiftool can directly access inodes, then the answer is no.  Exiftool does have it's `FileName` and `Directory` pseudo-tags which can be accessed and manipulated.